# Windows Store App - C# - Https Client Authentication

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-store-apps, authentication

I'm trying to implement Https Client Authentication in my application but I am having trouble finding any documentation on how to do it.

Looking through the MSDN documents I came up with this

```
// Certificate file in DER format (.cer or .p7b)   
string CountriesFile = @"Assets\https-client.keystore.cer";
StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
StorageFile file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(CountriesFile);

// Read the file into a buffer
IBuffer buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

// Create the Certificate object
Certificate ClientCert = new Certificate(buffer);
HttpBaseProtocolFilter aHBPF = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
aHBPF.ClientCertificate = ClientCert;

// Create our http client and send the request.
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(aHBPF);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);
```

I put this code together looking at the docs for [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx), [HttpBaseProtocolFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.aspx) and [Certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.certificates.certificate.aspx). Making the assumption that I should have the certificate in the required format and read the file into the `Certificate` class.

The above code doesn't work and throws this error

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in MyLib.DLL but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: The certificate specified is missing the required private key information.
```

I have tested my server set-up and it works with client auth through a browser, which leads me to two possible conclusions.

1. The certificate file is in the wrong format (though I would have hoped the exception would get thrown when the `Certificate` class is constructed).
2. This is not intended way to do it!

Any one know how it should be done?

Comment: On the HRESULT 0x80072F7D, please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019697/tls-client-certificate-authentication-on-uwp-windows-store-app) and the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you have to install the certificate at a User level before you can effectively use it for client authentication within a Windows Store App

```
// Needs to be a PKCS12 (p12/pfx) file
string certPath = @"Assets\https-client.keystore.p12";
StorageFile file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(certPath);
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
string certData = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(buffer);

// Will ask the user if they want this app to install the certificate if its not already installed.
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
     certData,
     "PASSWORD",
     ExportOption.NotExportable,
     KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
     InstallOptions.None,
     "MyFriendlyName");
```

Now the certificate is installed, it will be available to us in the certificate store.

```
var certificate = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(new CertificateQuery() { FriendlyName = "MyFriendlyName" });
ClientCert = certificate.Single();

HttpBaseProtocolFilter aHBPF = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
aHBPF.ClientCertificate = ClientCert;

// Create our http client and send the request.
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(aHBPF);
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);
```

I would prefer to be able to make the certificate available to only the application and will update this answer if I find a way of doing it.

Comment: When I use this code, I get the message "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F7D" Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Same here. This thing is starting to drive me crazzy.

Comment: Do you have no choice but to install the certificate? Can I do it all in code without going to the user store?

Comment: My understanding is that [ImportPfxDataAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298295.aspx) add the certificate for the app's use only and not for the user. But the doc's don't appear to be clear on this.

Comment: The error 0x80072f7d is WinHttp: 12157 ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_CHANNEL_ERROR. It simply means that the connection could not be established because the client certificate was not available (could not be used/trusted).